# Expressions not evaluated

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have the following code into a user-control

`<td class="column <%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>" >`

and it's working ok, with the correct CSS class output from the GetCssClass method. But I also have some other cells of that table with the following code

`<td class="column <%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>" runat="server" Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>"`

there are some problems, and the method GetCssClass is not evaluated, but instead it's literally sent to output.

Any help? (I'm a new asp.net developer)

Comment: the `visible` or the `class` parameter have the problem ? (or both ?).

Comment: Can you elaborate "there are some problems"?  Is ShowColumn value is being set properly?

Comment: Sorry because of the few details given.

The visible part is working, only the class is not working. Also, I've tried to remove the "column" class and it seems to work.

So: 

`<td class="column <%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>" runat="server" Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>"` 

does not output class content properly but 

`<td class="<%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>" runat="server" Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>"` 

does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we try to pass a parameter/object to a `runat="server"` line we use the `<%# ..%>`

You can use the `Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>` where the `ShowColumn` is a Boolean.

How ever in this case `class="column <%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>"` you are not try to pass a parametre but a string, and for that the `<%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>` is taken as a string.

This `class="column <%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>"` is converter to string, and render as string. An alternative to render the string of the return of GetCssClass, is to use the `<%= %>` that convert to string the value and place it on html (not passed to the control)

This `class="<%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>"` is place to the class the return of the GetCssClass

This `Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>"` place on the Visible variable the ShowColumn value.

Comment: But `<td class="<%# GetCssClass(SomeAttributes) %>" runat="server" Visible="<%# ShowColumn %>"` works...

Comment: @XaviIvars yes its works because you do not have place string before, so is remains object.